# VB.net Serialization Issue

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, settings, serializable, user.config

I'm trying to save the following class to the user.config and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Is the dictionary object not allowing the class to be serialized?

```
<Serializable()>Public Class RunInformation
    Public ExecutablePath As String
    <NonSerialized()> Public Settings As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    <NonSerialized()> Public ProcessId As Integer
    <NonSerialized()> Public Handle As IntPtr
    <NonSerialized()> Public TabPageHandle As IntPtr

    Public Sub New()
        ExecutablePath = ""
        Settings =  New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Saving:

```
Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    my.Settings.Setting = New RunInformation()
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

XML File:

```
<userSettings>
    <BotManager.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="Setting" serializeAs="Xml">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </BotManager.My.MySettings>
</userSettings>
```

Comment: When you open the Settings UI editor there is no Dictionary listed because standard XML serializers dont work with them.

Comment: I have the setting configured as so: http://imgur.com/a/0PRco

Comment: Still, `RunInformation.Settings` is not XML serializable because it is a `Dictionary<TK, TV>`

Comment: I know that dictionaries don't implement ISerialization interface. I was hoping marking that property NonSerialized would be a fix. Is this not the case?

Comment: It looks like the only thing you want to save is `ExecutablePath`?  if so, why not just save that as a string setting?

Comment: I'm actually trying to save a list of RunInformation and I may add more properties to RunInformation in the future.   `<Serializable()>Public Class Bots
        Public Items As New List(Of RunInformation)
        Public Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your serializing the info as XML but using the binary serialization control attributes.

Use the attribute `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore` instead